# Yii complex query in criteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have one search criteria. Now I need an complex query

as following in MySQL

```
SELECT id, location_lat, location_lng, ((location_lat - $lat)*(location_lat - $lat) + (location_lng - $lng)*(location_lng - $lng)) as distsqr FROM revite.tbl_event where location_lat is not null and location_lng is not null order by distsqr;
```

Yii-- criteria is as follows

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('name', $model->name);
```

how can add or combine above MySQL query into above criteria?

please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: It is obvious you have not bothered to read the Yii documentation on Db Criteria. Please do that and come update your question with more meaningful information. Try some code, and come back and explain where it is failing. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria and http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/06/cdbcriteria-in-yii/ for starters.

Comment: Yes, I read the doc. also I solved my problem, its easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->addSearchCondition('name', $model->name);
 $criteria->addCondition('location_lat is not null and location_lng is not null');
 $criteria->order = '(location_lat - :lat) * (location_lat - :lat) + (location_lng - :lng) * (location_lng - :lng)';
 $criteria->params[':lat'] = $lat;
 $criteria->params[':lng'] = $lng;
```

Comment: Upvote for solving your own problem, and posting back your solution.